# jQuery: Preventing multiple inputs at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I am writing a jquery code which should switch the input chars with chars I defined in a variable. So far the code works nicely if you carefully only press one char at a time. But as soon as you hit multiple chars at once you start breaking the result. What kind of options are there to make jquery either only take one char at a time or properly read out and convert multiple chars.

The results of multiple chars pressed too fast or pressed similarly result in having the string of the variable having chars mixed up or/and having some chars from the multiple inputs mixed in.

I learned already about the .prop() function to disable input, but even if I disable Input I cannot prevent multiple chars being passed into the function.

Thank you guys in advance,
cheers

HTML:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        String.prototype.removeChar = function(){
            var string = "";
            for(var i = 0, length = this.length-1; i<length; i++){
                string += this.charAt(i);
            }
            return string;
        }
        var name = "Some Random Name",
            length,
            sub = "",
            event,
            array=[];
        $("form").on("keyup", function(e){
            event = e.keyCode;
            if (e.keyCode === 8){
                length = $(".input").val().length;
                sub = sub.removeChar();
                $(".input").val(sub);
            }else{
                length = $(".input").val().length;
                sub += name.charAt(length-1);
                $(".input").val(sub);
                }
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>Who should be President?<input type="text" name="president" class="input"></form>
```

Comment: then just add maxLength="1" in your html input

Comment: Seriously this is a very nice and easy solution! Works flawlessly.

Comment: the maxlength you mean?

Comment: yes, but still I am wondering if there is a way to fix this inside jQuery

Comment: yep I see your problem is the double T it seems your js code needs modification

Comment: Yeah the double T is a new problem, which i guess i can fix by myself later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
  sub += name.charAt(length-1);
```

to

```
sub = name.substring(0, length);
```

Idea is to just get the total number of characters typed by the user and fetch that many characters from the `name` variable using [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) function

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        String.prototype.removeChar = function(){
            var string = "";
            for(var i = 0, length = this.length-1; i<length; i++){
                string += this.charAt(i);
            }
            return string;
        }
        var name = "Some Random Name",
            length,
            sub = "",
            event,
            array=[];
        $("form").on("keyup", function(e){
            event = e.keyCode;
            if (e.keyCode === 8){
                length = $(".input").val().length;
                sub = sub.removeChar();
                $(".input").val(sub);
            }else{
                length = $(".input").val().length;
                sub = name.substring(0, length);  // this is the change
                $(".input").val(sub);
                }
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>Who should be President?<input type="text" name="president" class="input"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
$(".input").val(sub);
```

to

```
$(".input").val(name.substring(0, length));
```

then change your condition to

```
if (e.keyCode !== 8){
    length = $(".input").val().length;
    sub += name.charAt(length-1);
    $(".input").val(name.substring(0, length));
}
```

In this condition you do nothing if you click back button

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        String.prototype.removeChar = function(){
            var string = "";
            for(var i = 0, length = this.length-1; i<length; i++){
                string += this.charAt(i);
            }
            return string;
        }
        var name = "Some Random Name",
            length,
            sub = "",
            event,
            array=[];
        $("form").on("keyup", function(e){
            event = e.keyCode;
            if (e.keyCode !== 8){
                length = $(".input").val().length;
                sub += name.charAt(length-1);
                $(".input").val(name.substring(0, length));
            }
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>Who should be President?<input type="text" name="president" class="input"></form>
```

Comment: your answer is really nice and very helpful but was not quite what I was looking for. Nevertheless good and useful input. Thx!

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies I updated my answer it is now bug free

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the whole input val with the random name and cut the val short

```
 $("form").on("keyup", function(e){
            event = e.keyCode;
            if (e.keyCode != 8){

                length = $(".input").val().length;
                //sub += name.charAt(length-1);
                $(".input").val(name.substring(0, length));

                }
        });
```